# Symfony2: Check authentication before checking the route

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I'm working on an restricted API. All routes (wether they exist or not) should return a 401 if the user is not authenticated. Unfortunately I'll only get the 401 if the route exists. If it doesn't exist I get an 404.

Is there a way to check the authentication **before** the route is checked? Maybe a wildcard route?

Comment: A [KernelRequest Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html) would probably do the trick. You can check if the request contains any authentication headers and throw a 401 response otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but this will return a 500 if I check for authentication on a non existing route. See following message: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL" (just tested it ;) )

Comment: Well I am confused.  Your question indicates your get a 404 if the route does not exist.  Your comment says 500.  Big difference. Which is it?  Perhaps clarify your question a bit.

Comment: It will return a 500 if I use an EventListener as suggested by Oldskool!

Comment: In that case, perhaps update your question with your listener code.  Seems like all you need to do is to check if the route does not exist and return a 401 response.  I don't see why you are checking the token storage at all.

Comment: Disagree. The question explains the problem I have. The thing I tried with the Listener was one possible/suggested solution that failed. BTW I'm not asking to return a 401 instead of 404 but to first check if the user is authenticated and only after that to check for the route.

Comment: Still be nice to see the code.  I would have a Kernel.Response (not request) listener which would simply check for a 404 response and change it to 401.  http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html

Comment: This is bad application design. Don't do this. Your behavior mean that every requested resource in your application exists. So, when i request for example: `/api/fake` - i will receive **401** code, accordingly, if I'm logged in I expect receive something **OK** for this resource. But i will receive **404**. Make it simple and more clearer (with expected behaviors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to match a ANY route, something like:

```
any_route:
    path:     /{anyparams}
    defaults:
        _controller: YourProjectBundle:Index:anyroute
    requirements:
        anyparams: ".+"
```

> But make sure is defined at the end

So, "non existent" routes now exists and will throw 401 error

Comment: Yep, that's what I had to do. Added a generic URL which will throw a 404 Exception when called. This way the Authentication takes place before symfony would usually throw the 404.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it's the correct behaviour - ie. if a route doesn't exist, it should return a 404... Maybe explain why you would want to ALWAYS return a 401. Shouldn't your clients that are consuming the API check for a 404?
Sorry, wanted to comment, but haven't got enough of a reputation to do so yet..

Comment: I want to return a 404, but **only** if the user is authenticated.

To clarify: not authenticated, route exists => 401; not authenticated, route doesn't exist => 401; authenticated, route exists => 200 (or something else); authenticated, route doesn't exist => 404

Comment: Yes, I understand... I'm just wondering why you can't return a 404 on a non-existent route. Doesn't seem to make much sense to authenticate against a route that isn't available...

Comment: The customer wants it to be a super restricted API. You are not allowed to get **any** information about the API without authentication.

Comment: Ok, in that case maybe use an event listener as suggested above and inspect the request headers for authentication...

Comment: Also, I've been using Guard recently and quite enjoy it... http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html

Comment: I tried, but it will return a 500 if I do so (see above; no route = no authentication)

Comment: Setting the priority so it gets triggered earlier might work?

Comment: By default firewall listener is called after router listener - not sure if there is any easy way to change that. You can try to change priority of `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall` listener.